# Running tests as usual against docker containers or dockerize tests?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, docker, continuous-integration

I'm new to Docker and was reading up on Docker. It's a great way to test systems in a self contained and reproducible standardized configuration (when done correctly).

However, in all the things I've read, there doesn't seem to be too much emphasis on how the testing should occur with docker containers. The docker is used to "contain" the infrastructure and application (code) for easy testing (as well as deployment). But sometimes test codebases are be large and not so simple too. And one can have a test codebase for API tests, another for UI, etc.

What is or should be (as determined at some point) the standard practice for testing docker containers/deployments of your applications/infrastructure? Should:

- the test code be deployed the old conventional way, as file repository you pull from somewhere and just then run on Jenkins server/slave or one's localhost for dev/QA testing/debugging, with the tests targeting apps in docker container?
- dockerize the whole test code base as a self contained container and then using that container to launch/execute tests against the other containers that have the app code/system infrastructure?
- combine the tests as part of the individual docker containers themselves to be run when/as needed. But I would think this works best only for unit tests that really pair with the container that holds the matching app code. Integration, UI, system level tests are different in association to app modules within the system.

The only reason I can think of that make dockerizing tests perhaps useful is that it's a single container with all the tests you need and the matching test infrastructure (all the test platform/language dependencies) so that one can deploy and run tests anywhere together with the matching app code containers. Saves one from having to set up test infrastructure when/as needed. But no seems to have blogged about such a thing for dockerized tests.

Comment: on a related note, test tools like Selenium have been dockerized: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium, https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium. Yet tests themselves I've not heard of being dockerized.

Comment: Some other instances of dockerized testing I've found: [Dockerizing BDD : Presentation at #BDDX15 Conference London](http://shashikantjagtap.net/dockerizing-bdd-presentation-at-bddx15-london), [Dockerizing Cucumber-BDD and Ruby Friends](http://shashikantjagtap.net/dockerizing-cucumber-bdd-and-ruby-friends), https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robotframework-users/r3FzTXle_w4, https://github.com/klevermonicker/robot_framework

Answer (score 5):

I prefer your option (3) i.e. to include test code in the production deployable artifact (the docker image)

Will quote [Alister Scott](https://watirmelon.com/) from [GTAC 2015](https://developers.google.com/google-test-automation-conference/2015/presentations#Day1Presentation5) which I attended:

> Don’t be afraid to add testability specific features to your app that don’t serve a functional purpose. I recently had to get new tyres on my car and realized that a lot of tyres have testability features called tread indicators. These don’t serve a functional purpose

For integration and e2e tests, i.e. tests that require more than 1 docker image to be used, I prefer [CI tool](http://12factor.net/build-release-run) that, through [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/), and a separate git repo for these tests, orchestrates the creation of all containers that are needed for the larger test. Again the docker images used [should be the exact same as for production](http://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity) except [what varies is the configuration](http://12factor.net/config) (e.g. environment variables) that make the tests point to test data and/or staging services.

Comment: Thanks for the response. For the integration/e2e case, where would the test code reside? External to docker or composed on the fly into a special test container to run against the system app that's spread across containers talking to each other?

Comment: Welcome. I added that into my answer, I prefer a separate git repo for integration/e2e tests since they touch more than 1 microservice therefore they don't belong to any of them in particular.

Comment: @Leo How are you using docker-compose through a CI server? I'm currently struggling with docker-plugin for Jenkins. Thinking about implementing the feature myself (https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-plugin/issues/74). By the way great job with the Selenium grid images.

Comment: I don't use the docker-plugin for Jenkins but do everything through bash scripting, if the plugin adds the missing features I may consider giving it another try ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'd dockerize the tests themselves as the process that runs the tests.

For example if you need to run unit tests in php with phpunit, you would dockerize [phpunit](https://hub.docker.com/r/phpunit/phpunit/) and use that to run tests against your code, and similarly for any other test framework you use (i.e. testng, junit... etc.)

Here's an example of the Dockerfile I use to encapsulate Java/Maven/TestNG for a Java test project which includes some selenium tests:

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-8

# Selectively add stuff we need
COPY pom.xml /usr/src/testng/

# Get a clean build immediately after and 'go-offline' to improve subsequent builds
RUN cd /usr/src/testng && mvn dependency:go-offline
COPY src /usr/src/testng/src
WORKDIR /usr/src/testng/

# Additional support files that's needed but not for the build
COPY supportfiles /usr/src/testng/supportfiles

CMD [ "mvn test" ]
```

Comment: Well, tests could be either side by side w/ product code or separate, I'm thinking of general/all cases. Though at present it is separate. And I'm talking about end-to-end/system/integration/regression/functional/UI tests, not unit tests.

Comment: OK so I think the same idea applies - you would dockerize whatever process runs your tests.  I'll update the answer with an example

Comment: It's not clear from the example you gave, as the default entrypoint is "mvn test". So does that mean all the test files are bundled into the docker image so that when you run the docker image (and pass "mvn test" as needed as parameters to docker run) that it looks for the test files within the container or does it look for the test files relative to the working directory where docker run is invoked?

Comment: `mvn test` is just an example command, but in this case `mvn test` would execute all the tests for the java maven project.  Setting it as a CMD just makes it run that as the default if you don't specify a command to run with your container.

So for example: `docker run testng` will run the default `mvn test` command vs. `docker run testng "mvn test -Dgroups=basic" will run a specific group of the mvn test.

Your commands will obviously be different but the basic idea is that the docker container should be built with all the files needed for your test commands

Comment: Ok, got it. Which means in this case of mvn, that the tests are bundled into the image. Because mvn looks within a fixed structure relative to where mvn is executed for code to run including tests. If I'm not mistaken (still new to docker), the execution path is relative to the root/working directory of the contents in the image, and not the working directory of where "docker run" is executed? If so, then what you just state in a way also means "dockerize the test runner, and it's dependencies which usually means bundle the tests with the test runner that you are dockerizing".

Comment: Actually, for this example, I guess you could map a subset of the mvn directory to a filesystem on the docker host to point to a different set of tests than the default packaged with the container image, as I recall there is a flag parameter with Docker run to map a directory in container to directory on docker host.

Answer (score 1):

Look closely at the screenshot I provide on this page: https://github.com/djangofan/karate-test-prime-example   This is an example project I made that shows how to do a test container in context with a service and returning an exit code at the end of the tests.

Then when your code is released by a pipeline, before it goes live, your Docker container will include an exit code that allows your pipeline to decide whether to roll it back or not.